# Submit de varios forms com AJAX, um de cada vez

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Tenho um código que eu pego com o PHP os alunos cadastrados no meu banco, e faço um for para que tenha 1 form para cada aluno. Cada form possui seu button submit, que o leva a função AJAX para serialize do form.

Esse é a tag do meu form (que fica dentro do `for` do PHP)

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="#" id="form1" class="form">
```

O submit dele

```
<button onclick="saveAluno(); return false" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">
```

e esse é o meu AJAX para serializar

```
function saveAluno(){
var data1 = $('.form').serialize();
console.log(data1);
$.post("controller/setters/addAlunoRotina.php", $('#form1').serialize(), function (response) {
    alert("Salvo com sucesso!");
}); }
```

Desse jeito ele está serializando todos os forms juntos, de uma só vez. Existe algum jeito de eu conseguir serializar um por um desses forms?

Essa é uma imagem dos forms do meu sistema, talvez assim seja mais facil entender o problema; 
[image]

Comment: Existe a necessidade de ser um form para cada aluno? Acho que o correto nesse caso é usar apenas um form para todos, pois você está tratando o mesmo "objeto" aluno. Se você for tratar objetos/temas diferentes, aí até faz sentido ter mais de um form.

Comment: @EdsonHoracioJunior infelizmente, existe a necessidade sim Edson.

Comment: No ajax você quer enviar apenas um form?

Comment: @EdsonHoracioJunior isso Edson, cada um dos forms tem seu botão enviar, eu quero que ao clicar enviar ele serialize apenas o form do botão. Vou editar meu post com uma imagem do sistema para ilustrar melhor;

Comment: Pera. Você quer que tenha, por  exemplo, 4 formulários e clicando em "Salvar" envie apenas o dado respectivo daquele formulário (ou seja, apenas um)?

Comment: Isso mesmo @Inkeliz

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O botão não vai mais enviar o form, no lugar o jQuery irá capturar toda vez que ele for clicado. Para isso, adicione na classe dos buttons o valor `bt_form`

```
<button class="btn btn-block btn-primary bt_form">
```

E agora adicione o código jQuery abaixo no lugar do saveAluno

```
// Toda vez que algum button for clicado
$('button.bt_form').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); // Cancela submit padrão do button

    // Faz a mesma coisa que saveAluno mas usa .closest para pegar o form do button
    var data1 = $(this).closest('form');
    console.log(data1);
    $.post("controller/setters/addAlunoRotina.php", data1.serialize(), function (response) {
        alert("Salvo com sucesso!");
    }); 
});
```

Comment: +1 Pela alternativa do closest

Comment: @EdsonHoracioJunior funcionou, valeu cara!!!

Comment: @Inkeliz Desculpa, tinha feito um comentário achando que você era o dono da pergunta, me confundi rs

Comment: Eu percebi (hahaa). Eu dei uma alternativa mais complexa e tinha ate me esquecido totalmente do "closest".

Answer (score 2):

Se exitem vários forms, com mesmo id: **Form + Button**

Altere isto:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="#" id="form1" class="form">
```

Para isto (partindo do principio que deva estar em um loop).

```
<?
 $i = 0; //EXEMPLO

while($mysql = $mysql->fetch_array()){ // EXEMPLO
?>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="#" id="form<? echo $i ?>" class="form">

<button onclick="saveAluno(<? echo $i ?>); return false" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">

<?
$i++; //EXEMPLO
} // EXEMPLO
?>
```

- Mudanças: agora cada formulário tem um id único.

**Javascript**

```
    function saveAluno(id){
var data1 = $('.form').serialize();
console.log(data1);
$.post("controller/setters/addAlunoRotina.php", $('#form'+id).serialize(), function (response) {
    alert("Salvo com sucesso!");
}); }
```

- Mudanças: o id do botão é o mesmo do form, que tem seu nome único.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta amigo!